# Rails changes action does not reflect deletion of associated entity.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes, model-associations

I have a `Note` model that `has_one` entity `Deadline` with nested attributes. Upon update of note, I check if the deadline was changed while updating using the `changes` method of rails.

This works fine for all cases except when I remove the deadline while updating. The params contain `:_destroy` but since this is not present in the db, `changes` does not give me anything. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Hi Jawad, I think I would need to know more about your goal in the broader picture.  I assume you're applying the `changes` method in the model?  If so, which one and how?  It would be helpful to see that code.  If it turns out there's a better way to serve your application than using `changes`, I would need to know more context about what you're trying to do to make that determination.

Comment: what are you doing after checking whether deadline has changed? If you want to perform same thing when deadline is deleted you can use after_destroy callback for deadline.  You can post few lines of code to be more clear about the scenario you are trying to achieve

Comment: @RohanPujari, thanks for the suggestion. That is what I ended up doing as well. I wanted to set the current time in the `last_updated_at` field of the note when it or one of it's associated records was actually updated. That included the removal of a deadline from note. I handled updated fields with `changes` and removed objects in the after_destroy of `Deadline` and the other associated models.

Comment: Nice to hear that @JawadKhawaja